# SPFX WebPart: Getting HTTPS certificate ERROR in IE11

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, pnpjs

Getting HTTPS certificate error in IE11, webpart is working fine in chrome, firefox, and Edge but NOT in IE11. The webpart is just displaying some simple list data in dropdown component, and nothing much complicated logic in webpart.

Error:
[image]

Anyone experienced this issue before, and how to solve it?

Comment: what version of SPFx are you using ? Is it also happening in a simple hello world webpart as well ?